# In many cases, the clothes people wear identify them/themselves as belonging to a particular social class

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

> In many cases, the clothes people wear identify them as belonging to a particular social class.

> In many cases, the clothes people wear identify themselves as belonging to a particular social class.

What is more natural, idiomatic or preferred between 'them' vs 'themselves' if you are a native English speaker?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first states that the **clothes** worn by people identify **them** (=the people wearing the clothes) as belonging to a social class. This makes sense. In some societies, people belong to social classes.

The second states that **clothes** worn by people identify **themselves** (=the clothes) as belonging to a social class. This makes no sense.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think you could clarify *why* "themselves" refers back to "clothes" and not to "people." I believe it is because "clothes" is the subject of the sentence. If you recast the sentence as "People often wear clothes that identify themselves as part of a particular class," then "themselves" refers back to "people," and thus would make sense.

Comment: Or, if you want to focus on the people: "In many cases, people identify themselves as belonging to a particular social class through the clothes they wear" or "...people choose clothing to identify themselves as belonging..."

Comment: Although I recognized the second sentence as sounding wrong, it didn't occur to me that "themselves" referred to the clothes. Probably because identifying oneself is something that normally only a person can do, so I intuitively attached it to the people.

Answer (score 1):

Tough question. Even as a native speaker, I originally disagreed with the accepted answer. But the reason that it's correct becomes clear if you explicitly add the implied (but missing) "that" within the sentence.

> In many cases, the clothes **that** people wear identify them as belonging to a particular social class.

This makes it clear that the sentence could be simplified (noun-verb-object) to:

> The clothes identify them as belonging to a social class.

That is obviously referring to people, whereas if you used "themselves", you would end up with

> The clothes identify themselves as belonging to a social class.

Which shows that the accepted answer is precisely correct.